# Отправка почты из HTML-формы

Tags: html, php

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как написать htmi код, чтобы из форм на сайте приходило содержимое этих форм мне на e-mail. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

**это в index.php**

```
// уведомление на емаил
            include_once ('include/mail.php');
            $mail = new mail; 
            $mail->send_comment(CONFIG_E_MAIL, LANG_SEND_MAIL_COMMENT_SUBJECT, $user_value, $email_value, $text_value);
```

**файл mail.php**

```
class mail 
{
    public function send_comment($from, $subject, $user, $email, $text) 
    {
        $message = '<html>'."\n";
        $message .='<head>'."\n";
        $message .='<title>mJournal - '.$subject.' '.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'</title>'."\n";
        $message .='<style type="text/css">'."\n";
        $message .='body { background-color: #000000; color: #FFFFFF; margin: 10px; padding: 0px; }'."\n";
        $message .='h1 { font-size: 18px; margin: 5px; padding: 0px; }'."\n";
        $message .='p { font-size: 12px; margin: 5px; padding: 0px; }'."\n";
        $message .='</style>'."\n";
        $message .='</head>'."\n";
        $message .='<body>'."\n";
        $message .='<h1>'.$subject.' '.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'</h1>'."\n";
        $message .='<p><b>'.LANG_USER.':</b> '.$user.'<br>'."\n";
        $message .='<b>'.LANG_EMAIL.':</b> '.$email.'<br>'."\n";
        $message .='<b>'.LANG_MESSAGE.':</b><br>'.$text.'</p>'."\n";
        $message .='<p>------------------------------<br>mJournal</p>'."\n";
        $message .='</body>'."\n";
        $message .='</html>';  
        $headers = "From: ".$from."\r\n" . 
        "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion() . "\r\n" . 
        "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n" . 
        "Content-Type: text/html; name=\"mJournal.html\" charset=utf-8\r\n" . 
        "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\r\n\r\n"; 
        mail($email, $subject, $message, $headers); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Никак. Пишите обработчик формы, использующий функцию [mail()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php).